# Referential integrity error when using infile, but no error when using mysql CLI

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

When I try loading a file of CSV data using the --local-infile option, I get the following error:

> ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`realtax`.`city_desc`, CONSTRAINT `city_desc_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cityid`) REFERENCES `city` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

The error happens at the first line of the CSV file (i.e., no rows get loaded at all).

Here is the actual mysql load command:

```
load data LOCAL infile 'out/desc.in' into table city_desc fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Here is the first line of the CSV file:

```
# head -1 out/desc.in
NULL,1000,"R4","B1","NWC125","SUNRISE ACRES #1 W 120 FT OF S 75",0.207
```

When I use the mysql CLI, however, I am able to load the first line without issue.  Here is the result:

> mysql> insert into city_desc values (NULL,1000,"R4","B1","NWC125","SUNRISE ACRES #1 W 120 FT OF S 75",0.207);
>   Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

Here is the line of table data to which it refers:

> mysql> select * from city limit 1;
>   +------+---------+-----------------+
>   | id   | prop_id | pidn            |
>   +------+---------+-----------------+
>   | 1000 |   10208 | S912999001L0800 |
>   +------+---------+-----------------+
>   1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Here are the SQL definitions for each table:

```
create table if not exists city 
(
    id              INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    prop_id         int,
    pidn            varchar(100)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1000, engine=innodb;

create table if not exists city_desc
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cityid          int not null,
    zoning          varchar(20), 
    state_cd        varchar(20), 
    map_id          varchar(20), 
    legal_desc      varchar(100), 
    legal_acres     numeric(5,5),
    foreign key (cityid) references city(id)
    on update cascade on delete cascade
) AUTO_INCREMENT=500000, engine=innodb;

create index propid_city on city(prop_id);
create index pidn_city on city(pidn);
```

I read the other threads about turning off the referential checks using:

> SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

but instead of hacking a fix, I would like to know the reason why this works manually but not with the --local-infile option.  The foreign reference is there (record id 1000), so why wouldn't it work?

UPDATE: Here is the information I received after running SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS right after the failed insert:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
121212 13:50:55 Transaction:
TRANSACTION 0 901853, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 3217, OS thread id 140224990570240 inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 492
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 9 row lock(s), undo log entries 9
MySQL thread id 15389, query id 1442612 localhost root
load data LOCAL infile 'out/desc.in' into table city_desc fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n'
Foreign key constraint fails for table `realtax`.`city_desc`:
,
  CONSTRAINT `city_desc_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cityid`) REFERENCES `city` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
Trying to add in child table, in index `cityid` tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
 0: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;; 1: len 4; hex 800ea15e; asc    ^;;

But in parent table `realtax`.`city`, in index `PRIMARY`,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 800003e8; asc     ;; 1: len 6; hex 00000007aed1; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 800000002d0110; asc     -  ;; 3: len 4; hex 800027e0; asc   ' ;; 4: len 15; hex 533931323939393030314c30383030; asc S912999001L0800;;
```

Comment: How many rows are in the csv file? Could it be possible that the referential problem exists on another row?

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that some rows would be inserted?  That's not the case.

Comment: It depends on if a transaction is used; in a transaction, it's either all or none.

Comment: There are no transactions in use -- I am doing a straight record insertion into a table, per the SQL definitions I included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you've presented, that row shouldn't have created any problem. Therefore, quick question: **how many rows are in the csv? If more than 1 row, does at least one of them contain foreign key value that isn't in the primary key?** 
If the row does indeed contain the data data, the error definitely isn't on that row; it is on a different row.

Comment: The CSV file contains almost 400,000 lines.  You say that the error is probably in another line.  Following that lead, I created an infile with just the first row of data.  I tried loading it using the infile command, and it worked!  This tells me that you're right.  I then opened the CSV file and closely scrutinized the data.  Indeed, there was one line where the foreign-key was set to zero, which is invalid.

Comment: I fixed my script to recognize empty columns, which caused this chain of events.  By not checking the auto-increment ID with each insertion, I was passing that error to the infiles. The load preparation script loads each line, one-by-one, into the first table (city).  I then grab the auto-increment id for that record and write out a CSV line to a series of text files (infiles). My script attempted to insert a record into the city table with an empty field, which choked.  When I retrieved the auto-increment id, it returned a zero.  Instead of bypassing, I passed this to the infiles.

Comment: That's good; I'm glad you got it resolved; you might need to pick one of the answers as the chosen answer; it gives you more points, and allows others to help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip first line in CSV file, add **IGNORE number LINES** opton.

```
load data LOCAL infile 'out/desc.in'
into table city_desc
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not a good solution.  The line itself is not the problem because 1) it works manually 2) I tried your suggestion and it still fails.

Comment: If I didn't select a database, or selected the wrong one, mysql would have told me in the form of an error.

Comment: Run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` after `LOAD DATA`. It will show detailed information about the error.

Comment: Please see the update to my initial comment.  I ran the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS command and posted the results.